# Problems with iterated nextLine function

Tags: java, string, input

I am trying to use user inputted N lines of N characters to do some operations with. But first I need to know N and another int being inputted. When I define N and the other integer K and then write 5 lines (in this case) of 5 characters each the program runs well. But when I use the represented String a (which I then would split into 2 ints, N and K, not shown here to not complicate things), an error occurs. Even if I now input 6 lines, being the 5 last of 5 characters each, the program gives an error of no line found for the multi function. I don't understand what's the problem, and if I remove the string a and just define N and K the program runs well. What's more surprising, the program runs if I use an interactive console instead of text input and write the terms one by one.

```
static String [][] vetor (int N) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String[][] multi = new String [N][N];
    for (int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++){
        String forest = scan.nextLine();
        String[] chars = forest.split("");
        for (int k=0; k<N; k++){
            multi[i][k]= chars [k];
        }
    }
    return multi;
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = scan.nextLine();
    int N = 5;
    int K = 5;
    String [][] multi = vetor(N);
```

I've tried many things, but I can't make sense of this. I didn't find any similar questions, but feel free to redirect me to an explanation.

Edit: This is a similar program one can run (with a possible input down (K<= N)) :

```html
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    static int[] numerificar() {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String Input = myObj.nextLine();
    String[] Inputs = Input.split(" ", 0);
    int size = Inputs.length;
      int [] a = new int [size];
      for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
         a[i] = Integer.parseInt(Inputs[i]);}
    return a;
      
   }
    static String [][] vetor (int N) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String[][] multi = new String [N][N];
    for (int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++){
        String forest = scan.nextLine();
        String[] chars = forest.split("");
        for (int k=0; k<N; k++){
            multi[i][k]= chars [k];
        }
    }
    return multi;
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a = numerificar();
    int N = a[0];
    int K = a[1];
    int cadeira = 0;
    String [][] multi = vetor(N);
    for (int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++){
        if (cadeira == 1) {
                    break;
        }
        for (int k=0; k<N-K+1; k++){
            if (cadeira == 1) {
                    break;
            }else if( multi[i][k].equals(".")){
                for (int j=0; j<K; j++){
                    if(multi[i][k+j].equals( "#")){
                        k+=j;
                        break;
                    } else if (j == K-1) {
                        cadeira = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cadeira);
   }
}
```

```html
5 3
.#.##
#####
##...
###..
#####
```

The output should be 1 in this case.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the input you're using? And also make this into a full program that we could run

Comment: @Joni Sorry for taking a while I went for dinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating more than one `Scanner` that reads from `System.in`. When data is readily available, a Scanner object can read more data than you ask from it. The first Scanner, in the `numerificar()` method, reads more than the first line, and those lines are not available to the second Scanner, in the `vetor()` method.

Solution: use just one Scanner object in the whole program.

```
public class Main {
    static Scanner globalScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  

    static int[] numerificar() {
        String Input = globalScanner.nextLine();
        String[] Inputs = Input.split(" ", 0);
```